# Expresión regular en PHP para números entre comillas

Tags: php, regex

Necesito extraer con una expresión regular sólo el número dentro de las comillas simples del texto:

```
onclick="javascript:Cargar('502235593');">
```

Condiciones:

1. Siempre aparece como `Cargar('502235593');">`, y
2. el número siempre tiene 9 dígitos.

El resultado debe ser un *array* con `502235593`.

La web posee muchos números que no sirven, por lo tanto la expresión regular que vengo intentando:

```php
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $web, $match);
```

No sirve, y necesito otra que sea más restrictiva para este caso en particular.

Comment: Por favor, agrega los casos que no quieras que coincidan. ¿Es siempre un número de 9 dígitos `/\d{9}/` ? ¿Siempre es la misma función `Cargar\('(\d+)'\)/` ? ¿Cuales sin las reglas?

Comment: siempre voy a tener esto: Cargar('502235593');">
que solo tome el numero que esta dentro de ello

Comment: siempre es un num de 9 digitos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expresión Regular:**

Personalmente, me olvidaría del `;">` final, que probablemente tenga más chances de cambiar. Esta expresión coincide con 9 dígitos dentro de la función:

```regex
/Cargar\('(\d{9})'\)/
```

**Descripción:**

- `Cargar\('` Coincide con el texto literal. El paréntesis se tiene que escapar porque es un [metacaracter](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.meta.php) para regex.
- `(\d{9})` Es un [grupo](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), que captura todo lo que coincide con el patrón que está entre paréntesis y lo devuelve como un item independiente en el array de resultados. Coincide con:

  - `\d{9}` Exactamente nueve dígitos consecutivos. Si se quiere otra cantidad, se puede usar `\d{8,11}` (entre 8 y 11), `\d{9,}` (9 o más), `\d{0,}` (0 o más, lo mismo que `\d*`), `\d{1,}` (1 o más, lo mismo que `\d+`), o cualquier [cuantificador](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.repetition.php).
- `'\)` Las comillas simples y el paréntesis de cierre del final literales.

**Código:**

```php
$tiene_un_numero = preg_match( "/Cargar\('(\d{9})'\)/", $texto, $coincidencias);

if ($tiene_un_numero) {
    echo "Se encontró: " . $coincidencias[1];
}
```

Al usar paréntesis en la expresión regular, el grupo define una captura extra. De esta forma, `$coincidencias[0]` devuelve todo el texto con el que coincidió, y `$coincidencias[1]` devuelve los 9 dígitos.

Si se busca más de un resultado, en vez de [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php), usamos [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php).

```php
$texto = 'onclick="javascript:Cargar(\'502235593\'); Cargar(\'123456789\');">';

$cant = preg_match_all( "/Cargar\('(\d{9})'\)/", $texto, $coincidencias);

echo "Se encontraron " . $cant . " coincidencias.";
foreach ($coincidencias[1] as $valor) {
    echo "\nSe encontró: " . $valor;
}
```

```
Se encontraron 2 coincidencias.
Se encontró: 502235593
Se encontró: 123456789
```

En este caso devuelve un array bidimensional. De nuevo, captura lo que coincide entre paréntesis, pero `$coincidencias[1]` es un array que contiene todos los resultados que coincidieron con el primer grupo.

Una página que me parece muy práctica para ver cómo queda el array de resultados es [phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), que ayuda a entender/recordar en qué orden devuelve cada item.

Por último, sabiendo que *podría* haber espacios opcionales en el texto antes y después de cada paréntesis, podríamos usar:

```regex
/Cargar\s*\(\s*'(\d{9})'\s*\)/
```

**Consideraciones extra:**

El caso descripto era relativamente sencillo. Sin embargo, al procesar HTML, las expresiones regulares fallan apenas se modifica levemente el código, o incluso no te permitirían distinguir entre el texto dentro de `onclick=`, de un texto que podría estar en cualquier otro lado del HTML. Por ese motivo, no recomiendo de ninguna manera usar regex para capturar texto dentro de un HTML en cualquier caso que sea apenas más complejo.

En cambio, accedería al DOM (*Document Object Model*). Existen muchas formas desde PHP. Para nombrar una, se puede usar la clase [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php). Viendo los ejemplos del manual de PHP, se nota que es muy sencillo y prácticamente igual a como se accede desde JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c9d3ccc2731b9043957b4b85529f35a19a2fa8d)**

```
preg_match_all("/^.*'([0-9]+)'.*$/", $web, $match);
```

[Ver en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/k3YMeM/3)